# Run specific code only once per session on App Start in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to run some code only 1 time per user session in my app.

Here is an example:

```
public class RunCodeOnce : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static bool ranOnce;

    void Awake()
    {
        if (ranOnce) { return; }

        ... code to run only once ...
    }
}
```

Is this a good method for doing this, or is there some other method of doing this that would be recommended?

Thanks.

Comment: It is 100% fine.

Comment: Awake is like a constructor so it will be only called once. Same with Start.

Comment: Depends. Maybe it doesn't have to be in `Awake` if it requires resources that are initialized later. Anyway your `bool` already solves it. You should still set `ranOnce` to true to be sure ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple answer is to have a singleton. Which is made when your game starts, runs the code, and basically because its never destroyed that start code never runs again.

Your code you had is almost all of it

```
public class RunCodeOnce : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static RunCodeOnce Instance;

    void Awake()
    {
        if (Instance!=null) { Destroy(gameObject); return; } // stops dups running
        DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject); // keep me forever
        Instance = this; // set the reference to it

        ... code to run only once ...
    }
}
```

this makes an object which persists, which no matter what will never allow a duplicate of itself and because it wont die no matter how much you load new scenes or whatever, unless you physically destroy it yourself in code, it wont die it will be there the whole session.

Comment: This makes sense but I'm curious what would make this better than just having a static bool? thanks for the example.

Comment: Because you can only have one copy.  It prevents it from being remade and resetting

Comment: I'm not sure I'm understanding. My bool is a static variable and I would only use it here. How would it be remade or reset? (hopefully this doesn't come off negative, I'm just curious and want to learn)

Comment: if you never reload the scene, or remake this object .. but then, what if it does .. this singleton blocks that from happening and also allows you to maybe reference values you needed to pick up such as userid, or, last score, or settings..

Answer (score 0):

In case by session you mean "since game launch", the Start/Awake methods already solve that problem, ensuring that script exists only in one instance.

But, if you rather mean "only once since the user install the app", you will have to leverage some persistent data to do the switch. the easiest way is the [PlayerPrefs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.html) class.

```
    void Awake()
    {
        Init();
    }

    void Init()
    {
        if (!PlayerPrefs.HasKey("isInit"))
        {
            DoYourStuffHere();
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("isInit", 1);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I meant one time every time the user launches the game by 'session', I should of been more clear about that. Thank you for the example though.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the [RuntimeInitializeOnLoadMethod](https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/RuntimeInitializeOnLoadMethodAttribute.html) attribute, like in the code example below. This will only be called by Unity once, until your app process is killed. 
The benefit is that it is super simple and completely independent from any MonoBehaviour,  unless you need references to assets over SerializeFields.

Note the enum [RuntimeInitializeLoadType](https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/RuntimeInitializeLoadType.html) can be set to `BeforeSceneLoad` or `AfterSceneLoad`.

```
using UnityEngine;

public static class Services
{
    [RuntimeInitializeOnLoadMethod(RuntimeInitializeLoadType.BeforeSceneLoad)]
    public static void Initialize()
    {
        Debug.Log("test");
    }
}
```